# Php address validation for locator

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, geolocation

I have a database table containing the address of whatever (irrelevant).

Now the problem is that if the row contains "Antwerp", "Antwerpen" or "Anvers" it is the same but off course the db doesn't know this.

I could have a db table containing all belgian cities, i could let user enter city via a selectbox this way there is no room for typo's and differt languages of the city.

This would work but in some cases I want to auto populate the input field with facebook data, but I cant figure a out how to determine which city matches the one from facebook since the language the city is in depends on the user.

Ideally I'd have a database table containing all cities and their translations but I haven't found one.

The only thing I could think of is dropping the autopopulate functionality... :(

Anybody has other suggestions?

Comment: How about utilizing a zip code? Does it have to be the city name? It's quite a bit easier to find a db of zip codes to cities :)

Comment: It can be anything but facebook doesn't return a zip code. Or at least not as often as it does the city name...

Comment: **Don't add solved to the title. If the answer is what you hoped for click the tick mark.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Harvest database from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_Belgium) or from [here](http://www.epictrip.com/Cities-in-Belgium-places-l57.html) (google for "belgium cities list"), or us this [world cities database](http://www.epictrip.com/Cities-in-Belgium-places-l57.html) (all results from google).

Than create table schema like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cities (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  state_id INT, -- If you want to
  name VARCHAR(255),
  status ENUM( 'confirmed', 'user_added')
  PRIMARY (id),
  INDEX (status),
  UNIQUE KEY (name)
)
```

You may also implement handling of synonyms like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLES synonyms (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    city_id INT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY(id),
    UNIQUE(nane)
)
```

Than you may either clone all values from cities to synonyms (data will have guaranteed integrity) and selecting will be easy or just synonyms (and write more complex inner join when selecting them) and use them only when setting new value.

Anyway in form you'll create field city (select box) with option like "not listed" which will allow user to add city manually (with state `user_added`) and administrator will have to check/add/delete/edit manually.

Comment: @issemdanny answers with the same scores (votes) are ordered randomly so they have equal chance of being read.

Comment: @issemdanny if this was answer to your question you should hit "okay mark" bellow vote buttons (so people will know that you got your answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/). Just send the address via GET request and use the returned `formatted_address` field. That should give you correct information.

I also tried the Google Places API once, but they give pretty bad results.

**[Example Code for PHP/MySQL](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlgeocode.html)** can be found here. You have to modify the example slightly, but it should give you a clue.

Comment: thanks but i forgot to mention i have looked in to this and i wonder what about... Note: the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions. ----> And: Note that this technique should not be used for geocoding databases with thousands of addresses, as this goes against the intended use of this service.

Comment: Correct. In my interpretation of the ToS, it is sufficient to just display a small static google map on the user profile (or in your admin interface). (But I am not a lawyer and will not give you any warranty).